# How to create a multiple dyanmic object reference in PHP?

Tags: php, object, syntax

I have a string with 'item->anotheritem'

I want to use this as a dyanmic variable. Is this possible?
e.g:

```
$string = 'item->anotheritem';
$obj->$string;
```

Ultimately trying to end up with the following, but it doesn't seem to like it. Any ideas?:

```
$object->item->anotheritem;
```

Using PHP Version 5.3.2

Answer (score 0):

In the first block of code, are you trying to parse the variable name as a string to the variable $string? It doesn't match what you are trying to doing in the second code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  First, you can manually break up the string and evaluate each element on the object, or second you can use PHP's `eval()` function.  I don't recommend the latter, though since it is *very* scary from a security standpoint.  Here is what those two mechanisms look like:

```
<?php
// Get some test data...
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->item = new stdClass;
$obj->item->anotheritem = "Goal!";
$string = 'item->anotheritem';

// Method #1
$target = $obj;
$parts = explode('->', $string);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $target = $target->{$part};
}
var_dump($target);

// Method #2 -- Avoid like the plague! ;)
$target2 = eval('return $obj->item->anotheritem;');
var_dump($target2);
```